# Como puedo crear un instalador para un servicio de windows en Visual Studiio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, servicio

Tengo un servicio básico, usualmente lo instalo de la forma básica es decir mediante el cmd con installutil pero ahora me gustaría hacer un ejecutable que simplemente me instalará el servició, estoy usando .Net 4.8 y visual studio con el legunaje  c#.
Me gustaría saber como podría hacer para generar el ejecutable, el servicio funciona .

Comment: que tipo de servicio? Normalmente podes realizar el ejecutable con boton derecho sobre tu proyecto y la opción publicar, pero si estas hablando de un servicio WCF no llega un archivo ejecutable.

Comment: SI es un WCF de los que se intalan en el sistema

Comment: Los queres levantar desde WAS o IIS?

Answer (score -1):

una solución podrías crear un Script en CMD que te ejecute ese comando.

Otra solución instalar la extensión Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects que te da plantillas de proyecto para crear tu instalador .msi , después de instalar este complemento debes cerrar visual studio, volver a abrir tu proyecto y en el explorador de soluciones dar clic derecho -> agregar -> nuevo proyecto -> buscar "Setup Project". 
Después en el nuevo proyecto creado le das clic derecho -> View -> sistema de archivos, dentro seleccionas la carpeta application folder y dentro del cuadro en blanco clic derecho -> add -> resultados de proyecto -> resultado principal, lo guardas.
Ahora en el Explorador de Soluciones clic en el y puedes configurar nombre, autor, etc, al terminar las configuraciones debemos dar clic derecho en el proyecto y Compilar, ahora puedes instalarlo ahí mismo con clic derecho en el proyecto e instalar o abrir carpeta en el explorador de archivos e instalar.

Aquí puedes encontrar más información detallada [Crear e Instalar Servicios de Windows](https://www.returngis.net/2011/01/crear-e-instalar-un-servicio-windows/)